# [: -le: unary operator expected

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I am writing a simple code that outputs the number of subdirectories in a directory that start with `00`. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxout=2

function getnumber {
    number=`ls | grep 00 | wc -l`
    return $number
}

qs=`getnumber`
echo $qs
if [ $qs -le $maxout ]
    then
        echo 'Youpiiii !!!'
else
    echo 'Sleeping for 60 sec'
fi
```

However I get the following error
`[: -le: unary operator expected`

When I `trace` my code, the function is working. I have

```
++ return 5
```

but

```
+ qs=
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you quoted your expansions (`[ "$qs" -le "$maxout" ]`), you'd get a more sensible error message. Right now, you have code trying to run something like `[ -le 2 ]`, and indeed, that's not valid. `[ '' -le 2 ]`, as the invocation would be with correct quoting, would give the `test` command the ability to emit a more correct error.

Comment: ...as another aside, consider using `getnumber() {`, not `function getnumber {`. The former syntax is POSIX-compliant and so will work with `/bin/sh`; the latter is a bashism, but (unlike a great many other bashisms which actually add value) has no benefit over the portable syntax.

Comment: As yet another aside, [don't try to parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you wanted to count the number of files containing `00` in their names, that might more properly look like so: `getnumber() ( shopt -s nullglob; set -- *00*; echo "$#" )` -- spawning only one subprocess, and that being a subshell `fork()`ed off with no `execve` following; compare to the original code, which spawns a subshell, and then from that subshell spawns three more, one to `exec` each of `ls`, `grep` and `wc`.

Answer (score 4):

The `` `...` `` notation captures what `...` *prints*, not what it *returns*. (`return` is mostly for indicating success vs. failure.)

So, change this:

```
number=`ls | grep 00 | wc -l`
return $number
```

to this:

```
number=`ls | grep 00 | wc -l`
echo $number
```

or just:

```
ls | grep 00 | wc -l
```

Comment: Certainly more correct, but I'd argue that in an ideal world we'd be dissuading the OP from using external tools *at all* for something the shell can do perfectly well with builtins alone.

Comment: then how can I assign the output of the function to a variable? I am not used to coding in bash. This is how I would do it in python. Thanks!

Comment: @aloha: You are already correctly capturing the output; it's just that output is populated via `echo` and `printf` and so on, not via `return`. If what you want is the exit status (which is what `return` sets), then you can check the value of the `$?` variable after the command completes. But that's not appropriate for the case described in your question.

Comment: Alright thanks. This is exactly what I need. Well this is a "toy" example. My code is more complicated then that. `$?` does the job